# Getting charged for "E2 Instance Core running in Seoul" but there is no VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

I'm being charged for "E2 Instance Core running in Seoul". The billing report says the related service is "Compute Engine", but there is no VM instance running from Compute Engine. I can't track the cause of the bill.

Not sure if it's related, but I created 4 Cloud Run services with 0 minimum instances auto-scaling settings and runs probably 0~5 mins per day. But the usage of the "E2 Instance Core running in Seoul" is 84 hours for 7 days. So I don't think that's the cause.

Why am I being charged for "E2 Instance Core running in Seoul"?

[image: Billing report for 7 days]

[image: Empty Compute Engine VM instances list]

Comment: Got a close vote for being a "community-specific reason". Sorry, but I can't understand. Can anyone provide some explanations? But not too harshly...

Comment: My thoughts are that it's something you should take up with GCP support. I think the reason this was voted to close was because the SO community couldn't help with an issue between you and GCP (if it is in fact that). If you've never created resources in Seoul then it's probably a mistake on their end.

Comment: Do you have a VPC Serverless Connector? Maybe being used by your apps in Cloud Run.

Comment: @FerreginaMasalo Yes, I do! I'm using one and its instance type is e2-micro. This might be the cause? (If so, consider answering this question so I can accept yours)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, when using a VPC Serverless Connector, this connector is charged as `e2-micro` instances as stated by [pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/pricing#serverless-vpc-pricing).

This is the reason why you see these charges even if you're not having a VM in GCE.

Also to confirm, you can use the following tip from the docs:

> You can view your Serverless VPC Access costs in the Cloud Console by filtering your billing reports by the label key serverless-vpc-access.

Comment: You might still get charged for the removed VPC Serverless Connector for a while. From the chat support: "After stopping/deleting an instance, please note that the charges will be finalized after 32 hours. In addition, sometimes there is a slight delay (up to a few days) in usage reporting. Here's the link for reference: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#faqs"

Answer (score 1):

There are two possiblities:

1. Resources were created in the wrong region due to a bug - contact billing support and explain everything. If they confirm that it's a bug you can file it on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).
2. Your account has been compromised - in this case I can recommend reading some documentation:

- [Compromised credentials](https://cloud.google.com/security/compromised-credentials)
- [Identify and secure compromised accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2984349?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-temporarily-suspend-the-suspected-compromised-user-account%2Cstep-investigate-the-account-for-unauthorized-activity%2Cstep-revoke-access-to-the-affected-account%2Cstep-return-access-to-the-user-again%2Cstep-enroll-in--step-verification-with-security-keys%2Cstep-add-secure-or-update-recovery-options%2Cstep-enable-account-activity-alerts)

Check the [login audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580120) and see for any unathorised / suspicious looking logins and [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging) for entries related to the resources located in Seoul. It may be in a different project (which would support "being hacked" version).